# What does $\in$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm reading a textbook on complex analysis and I've come across notation using this ($\in$) symbol. In the context of "an argument of $z = x + iy$ is a number $\phi \in \mathbb R$ such that $x = r\cos\phi$ and $y = r\sin\phi$" what does this symbol mean?

Comment: "Element of". It's universal, has nothing to do with complex analysis, $x\in S$ means $x$ is an element of the set (or class) $S$.

Comment: [Mandatory Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: And $R$ here is the set of real numbers.  So “a number $\varphi\in R$” is an obscure way to write “a real number $\varphi$”.

Comment: "obscure way"... :-P

Comment: $\in$  is atomic and has no definiton

Comment: @Amr: Some people might beg to differ.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Since you know a looot more than I do in set theory, I 'd like to hear your view about what I said

Comment: @Amr: The prime relation in New Foundations is in fact $\subseteq$, and you define $x\in y\iff \{x\}\subseteq y$. In algebraic theories the $\in$ relation is in fact defined by arrows, which are closer to functions than to the $\in$ membership, that is $\pi\in\Bbb R$ is translated to the statement that there is an arrow from a singleton into $\Bbb R$ and $\pi$ is its range (or image). In both these contexts, $\in$ is not the atomic relation; although personally, I am philosophically inclined to agree with your original comment.

Comment: Curious, which complex analysis textbook are you reading?

Answer (score 6):

$\phi\in R$ just means that $\phi$ is an element of $R$.

In this case it would mean that $\phi$ is an element of the set of real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

As $\in$ has $\LaTeX$ code of \in, $\phi\in\mathbb{R}$ means $\phi$ is element of set of real number $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\in$ means "is an element of", or "is in". If I had a set $S = \{1,2,3\}$, then $1 \in S$, but $4 \notin S$.

Comment: When posting an answer to a two-years old question, it is expected that you add information *not* present in the other two answers that were posted in a timely manner.